# Cython prange slowing down serial parts of code?

Tags: python, c, openmp, cython

In the code that I am writing, I have two functions: `Residue(u,f,h)` and `Relax(u,f,h)`

```
@cython.cdivision(True)
@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.wraparound(False)
@cython.profile(True)
cdef double[:,:] Residue(double[:,:] u, double[:,:] f, double h):
    cdef:
        Py_ssize_t i, j
        Py_ssize_t N = u.shape[0]
        double h2 = h*h
        double[:,:] res = np.zeros([N,N], dtype=DTYPE)
    
    for i in range(1,N-1):
        for j in range(1,N-1):
            res[i,j] = f[i,j] - (u[i-1,j] + u[i+1,j] + u[i,j-1] + u[i,j+1] \
            - 4*u[i,j])/h2
    return res

@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.wraparound(False)
@cython.profile(True)
cdef void Relax(double[:,:] u, double[:,:] f, double h):
    cdef:
        Py_ssize_t i, j, N
        double h2 = h*h 
    N = u.shape[0]
    for i in range(1,N-1):
        for j in range(1,N-1):
            u[i,j] = (u[i-1,j] + u[i+1,j] + u[i,j-1] + u[i,j+1] \
            - h2*f[i,j])/4
```

How they interact is that at some point, the output of `Residue` gets inputted as `f` inside `Relax`. These two functions are called multiple times during the runtime of the code.

Using `cProfile`, when I parallelize `Residue` by using `prange` on the outermost `for` loop, I see that the function gains a modest speed-up compared to the serial code (as expected). However, unexpectedly, the entire code takes longer to finish.

I have identified where it slows down: `Relax`, which has remained unchanged. For some reason, whatever gains I get from parallelizing `Residue` gets drowned by how much `Relax` gets slowed down. All other functions seem unaffected when I parallelize `Residue`. For example:

Serial code runtime: 14.840 seconds

| ncalls | tottime | function |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 5512 | 10.618 | Relax |
| 743 | 1.799 | Residue |

Parallel code runtime: 17.019 seconds **(+2.179)**

| ncalls | tottime | function |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 5512 | 12.745 **(+2.127)** | Relax |
| 743 | 1.622 **(-0.177)** | Residue |

As one can see, most of the slow-down is due to `Relax`. I can't seem to identify why this is so, when the only thing that has changed is `Residue`. I kind of suspect there might be some kind of variable type conversion that might be occuring once I use prange.

Comment: What is the target machine (especially the processor reference & memory)?

Comment: I am not sure if this answers your question, but I'm running this on an Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-7200 CPU @ 2.50 GHz, with 2 cores and 4 logical processors.

Comment: I though It was due to the creation of many thread per call but I am unsure of this regarding the processor (only 4 threads will be created). Indeed, an overhead of 2.127s for 5512 call means 386 us/call. Since 4 threads need to be created and they are probably done sequentially here, it means that threads would roughly takes 100 us to be created. This is consistent with measurement I made an several machine. That being said, it would also means that using threads is not faster at all. This is possible since the computation is memory-bound. This is why I asked the memory reference too.

Comment: To get the memory information you can read [that](https://www.alphr.com/check-ram-frequency/). On Linux, you can use the command `sudo dmidecode -t memory`. That being said, note that stencil codes like this can be optimized to be less memory-bound (ie. faster) when they are put in an iterative loop (although this is not trivial to do).

Comment: I think you are correct that it's because of the creation of too many threads. I was able to make a faster algorithm by editing the code so that the parallel version of `Residue` gets called only on the finer grids, and the serial version gets called on the coarser grids. Then I purposefully made it so that `Relax` gets called twice or thrice the amount, and found that the absolute amount of speed-up did not change. So it seems like `cProfile` might just be misassigning the lion's share of the overhead to `Relax` for some reason, instead of `Residue`?

Comment: However, the bigger lesson here might be that I just need a better workstation.

Comment: I did not fully understand the point about the profiler, but most profilers are not precise when function calls last for a very short period of time. As for the workstation, I am not sure it would help a lot. Having more core will increase the execution time if the problem is due to the threads creation. Having a higher frequency could help a bit but most processor do not go beyond 4.5 GHz and the computation is likely memory bound. Having a faster memory can certainly help but you should not expect more than a x3 speed-up on a modern personal computer. I guess big CPU caches could help a lot.

Comment: On the software side, you can try to create threads only once and change the code to be more cache-friendly although this is hard, especially in Python... Such optimizations could be then more effective on a better hardware.